# How to read extend ascii code in java

Tags: java, ascii

Hello today I have a problem to print extend ASCII code in java. When I try to print it. It does not display. How can I print it.

Comment: There is no "extended ASCII". There are ISO-encodings though. Which one did you use, and where do you want to print? Console, graphical widget, printer?

Comment: There's no such thing as extended ASCII, in that there was never a standardized set of glyphs corresponding to byte values over 127.  Do you want to print some Unicode characters that resemble a particular vendor's non-standard byte glyphs, like IBM's codepage 437?

Comment: this code is small like :     char c=(char)199; to prin extend acii code

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/index/extend.gif

Comment: That's [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: Yes that 's right how can we print it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String` constructor that takes a byte array and a character set to convert a [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) ("IBM extended ASCII") character to a Java UTF-16 `char`:

```
public static extendedAscii(int codePoint) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new String(new byte[] { (byte) codePoint }, "Cp437").charAt(0);
}
```

(Note: Yes, all characters in code page 437 fit in single UTF-16 `char`s; I checked.)